# How to sort without removing duplicates?

Tags: python, sorting

While sorting `(1,2,3,4,5,5)` it removes one 5 and prints `(1,2,3,4,5)`, but I want the output to be `(1,2,3,4,5,5)`.

Comment: is this a tuple or a list? You have to be specific about the datatype

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and post a [example] showing your code, the input data structure and the sorting.

Comment: Using `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)` makes it a tuple, which can't contain duplicates so the extra 5 is removed. What are you trying to sort?

Comment: tuples can contain duplicates, you are maybe thinking of sets.

Answer (score -1):

```
t = (1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5)
tuple(sorted(t))
>> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)
```